# Load data into extended Bootstrap table with colspan

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

Excuse me, now I am using [this](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) to make a table. Now I would like one table header to have this property, `colspan="6"`. However, how can I load data into this table?

Note. the table structure is:

```
<tr>
<th colspan="6" class="col-xs-4" data-field="status" data-sortable="true">Status</th>
</tr>
```

Note. the way I load data into bootstrap table is:

```
$("#table").bootstrapTable({data: data});
```

Comment: initialize `data` variable with some data.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap-table does not support `rowspan` and `colspan` Header temporarily.

More info : https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/182

Alternatively, you can try below solution

```js
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    columns: [{
        field: 'id',
        title: 'Item ID'
    }, {
        field: 'name',
        title: 'Item Name'
    }, 
    {
        field: 'price',
        title: 'Item Price'
    },
    {
        field: 'color',
        title: 'Item Color'
    },
     {
        field: 'size',
        title: 'Item Size'
    },
     {
        field: 'discount',
        title: 'Item Discount'
    }],
    data: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Item 1',
        price: '$1',
        color: 'Red',
        size: 'XL',
        discount: '20%'
    },{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Item 2',
        price: '$2',
        color: 'Green',
        size: 'L',
        discount: '30%'
        
    },{
    id: 'Total Items',
    name: 2
    }]
});


$('#table').bootstrapTable('mergeCells', {
 index: 2,
 field: 'name',
 colspan: 5
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.0/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.0/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table"></table>
```